# Make Facebook link previews work with ajax website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, facebook

Everyone knows if you copy a link from an html website on to facebook it will try to get available images like previews for the link. However, if the content is generated dynamically, like with js, facebook wont read that content. Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's preview mechanism lets you set your own metadata and change the preview image, title, short site description, etc.  In this case, you can set your preview image with:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/images_folder/image.jpg"/>
```

This is in accordance with the open graph protocol, which you can read more about here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, there is a problem. I already use those meta tags, however, the problem is I need to dynamically set an image. So i would also need to dynamically change the tag. Problem is, facebook wont read the javascript changes, so the problem remains

Comment: What do you mean dynamically set the image?  You mean change set the image on the page and in the meta AFTER facebook has crawled the page and the have changes reflect?  If so, then this is impossible.

Comment: then... if you say so, it is impossible. Thanks anyway for the help.